ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE in javascript using playwright app
Need your advice on how to resolve this error message "ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE" in javascript using playwright.
Your response is highly appreicated
Regards,
Ferdi
I am trying to login using authentication code. But its still showing this error "ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE"

Please share a [mcve]. Without the code, a site under test, a package.json and a description of what you're trying to accomplish, there's no way to help. Thanks.
